# Detecting disk throttling on Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, azure-vm

Is it possible to monitor disk IO usage on an Azure VM or in SQL Management to detect whether disks are being throttled? How would you do it?

Background:

I'm looking for a way to raise an alert when disk IO throttling begins on an old legacy system. The legacy system has a dedicated SQL Server 2016 instance running multiple databases per client. It runs as a virtual machine on Azure.